# Узнать наличие текста на изображении

Tags: c++, алгоритм, opencv

Есть массив изображений. Нужно выделить изображения содержащие текст.
Просто выделить, без нахождение того где этот текст находится.
Как это сделать? Интерсует хотя бы название алгоритма, без реализации.

Comment: Без распознавания - ещё куда не шло, но без нахождения - нееееее)) А так, интересно :)

Comment: Нейронная сеть?

Comment: То, есть, считаются и водяные знаки, и названия улиц на домах, и тексты на рекламных щитах, и надписи на заборе и асфальте? Ты можешь предварительно применить алгоритм выделения векторов, но шрифт может быть контурный как у Яндекса.

Comment: http://www.ctie.monash.edu.au/terry/text%20from%20images.pdf
Теоритически это возможно.
Точно можно узнавать есть ли субтитры в видео или нет.
Без всяких нейронных  сетей.

Comment: Любая нейронная сеть, реализующая задачу классификации изображений. Классификация на два класса: 1) в изображении есть текст; 2) в изображении нет текста.

Comment: Вы хотя бы пример изображений приведите. В общем виде задача не решена. Поэтому универсального алгоритма Вам никто не даст.